# Generating an extra indent to make an element a child of an outer block

Tags: pug

My data is a sorted array:

```
data = [ "Aa", "Abc", "Cc", "Cde", "Xx", "Yy" ];
```

How do I achieve a new `.col-sm-6` block each time the first letter of the element changes and for it to contain all those beginning with the same letter. For example the above `data` should result in:

```
.col-sm-6
  h4 A
  p Aa
  p Abc
.col-sm-6
  h4 C
  p Cc
  p Cde
.col-sm-6
  h4 X
  p Xx
.col-sm-6
  h4 Y
  p Yy
```

With the following code I have problems generating the extra markup indent for the `<p>` elements to be children of the `.col-sm-6`:

```
.row
  - data = [ "Aa", "Abc", "Cc", "Cde", "Xx", "Yy" ];
  - let firstLetter = "!";
  - for (let i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
  -   if (firstLetter!=data[i][0]) {
  -     firstLetter = data[i][0];
      .col-sm-6
        h4=firstLetter
  -   }
        p=data[i]
  - }
```

The above produces:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <h4>A</h4>
    </div>            !! in the wrong place
    <p>Aa</p>
    <p>Abc</p>
                      // </div> to be here
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <h4>C</h4>
    </div>
    <p>Cc</p>
    <p>Cde</p>
    ...
```

How do I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any tricks to add tags in the previously dynamically rendered element as by nature, pug doesn't share indentation between blocks.

The thing is that when pug reaches

```
  -   if (firstLetter!=data[i][0]) {
  -     firstLetter = data[i][0];
      div.col-sm-6
        h4=firstLetter
  -   }
```

it instantly closes the `div` when exiting the `if` block.

**My solution** would be to rework the logic so that we have every words beginning with a given letter when generating a new `.col-sm-6`.

```
//- arr an array of string
//- returns a Map where keys are letters and values array of words beginning with the key
- function mapByFirstLetter (arr){
-   const letters = new Map();
-    for (const word of arr) {
-       const letter = word.charAt(0)
-       if ( !letters.has(letter) ) {
-           letters.set(letter, [word])
-       } else {
-           const storedWords = letters.get(letter);
-           storedWords.push(word);
-       }
-    }
- return letters;
- }

//- words an array of string
//- render each word in a p
mixin renderWords(words) 
    each word in words
        p= word

div.row
    -data = [ "Aa", "Abc", "Cc", "Cde", "Xx", "Yy"];
    -const myMap = mapByFirstLetter(data)
    -for(const [key, value] of myMap) {
        div.col-sm-6
            h4= key
            +renderWords(value)
    -}
```

Note: I've written a new function inside the pug template but I recommend that you move that kind of computing in an upstream script to keep simple template files.

Comment: Using a mixin to render the list together with everything else in the block seems to be the only way. Thanks.